# Seleção de Receitas por Ingredientes Especificos

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Bom, estou criando um site de receitas e uma das pesquisas é uma pesquisa por ingredientes selecionados. Minha tabela no banco de dados é essa:

```
CREATE TABLE Receita(
  idReceita INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  nome_Receita VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  preparo  TEXT NOT NULL,
  ingredientes text not null,
  usuario_idUsuario int,
  categoria_idCategoria int,
  dificuldade_idDificuldade int,
  PRIMARY KEY (idReceita)
);
```

E meus ingredientes são separados por vírgula. Minha página html de pesquisa está assim:

```html
 <div class="container" style="margin-top:60px">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="//background-color:lavenderblush;">
                <label><h4>Digite os ingredientes que você tem em casa e nós selecionaremos as receitas que mais se enquadram na sua busca.</h4></label><br>
                <form action='processa.php' method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrediente 1" name="text1" class="form-control" id="text1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrediente 2" name="text2" class="form-control" id="text2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrediente 3" name="text3" class="form-control" id="text3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrediente 4" name="text4" class="form-control" id="text4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrediente 5" name="text5" class="form-control" id="text5">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrediente 6" name="text6" class="form-control" id="text6">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrediente 7" name="text7" class="form-control" id="text7">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrediente 8" name="text8" class="form-control" id="text8">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrediente 9" name="text9" class="form-control" id="text9">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrediente 10" name="text10" class="form-control" id="text10">
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" id='b' class="btn btn-default">Procurar</button>
                </form> 
            </div>
```

Minha ideia é pegar os valores inseridos na página:

```
<?php
            include "config.php";

            $i1 = $_POST["text1"];
            $i2 = $_POST["text2"];
            $i3 = $_POST["text3"];
            $i4 = $_POST["text4"];
            $i5 = $_POST["text5"];
            $i6 = $_POST["text6"];
            $i7 = $_POST["text7"];
            $i8 = $_POST["text8"];
            $i9 = $_POST["text9"];
            $i10 = $_POST["text10"];
```

E penso em fazer um explode nos ingredientes de cada receita e fazer um if com cada índice do array mas não sei se esse é o certo. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: "E meus ingredientes são separados por vírgula.", isso me parece ineficiente. Você pode criar duas tabelas (como `tabela_ingredientes` e outra como `receita_ingredientes`). Dessa forma o `receita_ingredientes` teria uma relação entre a `receita` e o `ingredientes`, que pode ser mais de um (uma relação M:N, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990459/how-to-create-tables-with-nm-relationship-in-mysql). Dai bastaria dar  um `INNER JOIN`. Já no HTML/CSS você pode usar `array` ou utilizar `Variable variables`, afim de evitar repitação.

Answer (score -1):

Não é o modo mais indicado mas seguindo o seu código aí, você pode usar LIKE e AND para as suas variaveis.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM Receita WHERE 
        ingredientes LIKE '%{$i1}%' AND
        ingredientes LIKE '%{$i2}%' AND
        ingredientes LIKE '%{$i3}%' AND
        ingredientes LIKE '%{$i4}%' AND
        ingredientes LIKE '%{$i5}%' AND
        ingredientes LIKE '%{$i6}%' AND
        ingredientes LIKE '%{$i7}%' AND
        ingredientes LIKE '%{$i8}%' AND
        ingredientes LIKE '%{$i9}%' AND
        ingredientes LIKE '%{$i10}%'
";
```